# How to make full height image with vertical text on center and left align witth background overlay image

Tags: html, css, sass

How to make full height image  that have on top black overlay(from to top to middle to bottom)

0% -> 35% -> 0%

```html
<header style="background: url(...image..);">
  <h2>title</h2>
  <p>description...</p>
</header>
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just write a basic `background-image` with `black overlay` code. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
header {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

header:before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.35), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1476820865390-c52aeebb9891?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80')">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Description...</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: the only problem is that i need url in html and not inside css  because i need to append  <?=$image['banner']?>   but this script work for other

Comment: I just update the above code snippet with few CSS changes. I move **background-image** from `css` to `html`. Thanks

Comment: hmm where is here the overlay  top: 0%   center  35%  bottom 0%  opacity ?

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot to update in my edit. I just added overlay **top opacity: 0**,  **middle opacity: 0.35** and  **bottom opacity: 0**. If you want to increase overlay in middle just change **0.35**. Thanks

Comment: tnx that help me a lot!